# (Python) subprocess.run/Popen is stuck on a blank window of the command line exe file it's running

Tags: python, subprocess, text-to-speech, mozilla

I'm trying to run a command line program (Mozilla TTS) with a Python script, using arguments, but it's stuck on a blank window. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```python
    process = subprocess.Popen(['tts', '--list_models'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while process.stdout.readable():
        line = process.stdout.readline()

        if not line:
            break

        print(line.strip())
```

But when I run it, it opens up the tts.exe window, and it just hangs there. But, when I do something like `process = subprocess.Popen(['pip', 'list'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, it actually works. The code below the subprocess call is for the shell to show live output of the program as if you're running the command itself on the terminal.

Comment: Not familiar with tts, but is it maybe waiting for input?

Comment: What happens when you run "tts --list_models" in a terminal?

Comment: @BenGillett When I do it, it actually works

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: @mayankagrawal Turns out that you have to run it in the terminal instead of IDLE or double clicking or anything